# Remove N first occurrences of a number in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have an ArrayList and I have to remove the first 2 instances of number 1

```java
public void remove(int num, int element) {

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1];
    // ...
}
```

`element` is the number inside myArray, `num` is how many times I have to remove the element.

So if `num` is 2 and `element` is 1, the ArrayList will contain `[2, 2, 1]`

How can I do it? I've tried a for loop but I don't know how to write the 'how many times'. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

First, it may be needed to make sure that the input list contains at least `num` occurrences of the needed elements, that is, the appropriate indexes should be tracked and as soon as the `num` elements is detected, the elements at these indexes are removed:

```java
public static void removeNFirst(ArrayList<Integer> list, int num, int element) {
    int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(i -> list.get(i) == element)
        .limit(num)
        .toArray();
    
    // make sure at least num elements are found
    if (indexes.length < num) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = indexes.length; i-- > 0; ) {
        list.remove(indexes[i]);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3));
System.out.println("Initial: " + list);
removeNFirst(list, 3, 1);
System.out.println("Removed three first 1: " + list);
removeNFirst(list, 2, 2);
System.out.println("Removed two first 2: " + list);
```

Output:

```
Initial: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3]
Removed three first 1: [2, 2, 3]
Removed two first 2: [3]
```

Comment: but it will not be always remove two elements, the number of elements of a specific type that needs to be removed is also passed as  an argument to the method

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani, yes, the title of the question misled me a bit, so the updated answer removes exactly `num` matching elements.

Comment: Well, if you know for sure that `num` is always two, you can simply use `list.remove((Object)element); list.remove((Object)element);` For an arbitrary `num`, I’d replace `toArray()` with `reduce((a,b) -> b)` to find the index of the last element to remove, followed by `list.subList(0, lastToRemove + 1).removeIf(o -> o == element);` as this avoids copying the remaining elements `num` times.

Answer (score 2):

> **SHORT ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION:**

You can keep on reducing the number till it reaches 0. If the number matches the element, then you can remove it.

> **QUESTION THAT NEEDS TO BE THOUGHT UPON:**

What to do in case the number of elements to be removed are more than those present in the  list .
for example in case of your array, what if it had been element 1 to be removed more than 4 times.

> **SAMPLE SOLUTION:**

The logic i'm providing below works for the case when the number of elements to be removed are always less than or equal to the elements present in the  list.

```
public class Swtich {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        remove(2,1);
    }

    public static void remove(int num, int element) {

        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(1);

        System.out.println(arr);
        int i = 0;

        while (num > 0) {
//          System.out.println(arr);
            if (arr.get(i) == element) {
                arr.remove(i);
                num--;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

and the output is as follows :

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: So if num is 2 and element is 1, the ArrayList will contain [2, 2, 1]
-> i think OP has specified the values num and element,

Comment: but the OP says result should be [2, 2, 1] , am i missing st ?

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes man, thanks, realized my mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void remove(ArrayList arr, int num, int element){
    int removeCounter = 0;
    while (removeCounter != num) {
        arr.remove(arr.indexOf(element));
        removeCounter++;
}
```

You can use a counter like in my code... Also you should create ArrayList outside of the method block so you can print it in main method.

Answer (score 1):

Combine an `iterator` with an `counter`.

```
public void remove(int num, int element) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1];
    Iterator<Integer> arrIterator = arr.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while(arrIterator.hasNext() && num > count) {
        if (arrIterator.next().equals(element)) {
            arrIterator.remove();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1];` Never seen that syntax before and can't find any mention of it in documentation?

Comment: I copied it from his example. Very unlikely this will actually compile, but if you want to make sure ask OP.

Answer (score 0):

Call `remove(Object)`, which removes the first instance found, n times:

```
Integer numberToRemove = 1; // note: must be Integer
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    arr.remove(numberToRemove);
}
```

Note that for `List<Integer>, you must remove an` Integer`, otherwise the` remove(int)` method will be called which removes the element at position, rather than by value.

Comment: but it wont always be number 2  ,right?

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani I meant `1`, but yes, it will always be `1` because that’s what OP wants.

Comment: Element is the number inside myArray, num is how manytimes I have to remove the element. So if num is 2 and my element is 1, the ArrayList will contain = [2, 2, 1]
-> the OP is giving an example case and not necessarily the same value will be provided

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani fine. See edited answer.